# aws sam cli build - how to avoid pip install every build

Tags: aws-lambda, pip, aws-sam

When developing a lambda using `sam` cli, I often need to run `sam build` which create a new image from my `Dockerfile`

This process include fetching all the dependency:

`RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .`

And takes a lot of time, I'm looking for a way to avoid this step, but couldn't find any info about it

I figure this solution, run `sam build`, and use the generated image as a base for the next run (and remove the pip install cmd)

it is working, but I was wondering if it is a good practice or can it cause problems later?

any other solutions?

Comment: Have you considered creating an image of the lambda layer with SAM CLI and caching it locally?

Comment: How is it different than what I suggested? can u elaborate?

Comment: I just thought about running `sam build` with `--cached` flag. By default, SAM builds are [not cached](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-build.html).

Comment: No, `--cached` does not prevent pip from running